# Intel Ultra Path Interconnect (UPI) Bandwidth

Tags: benchmarking, intel, hardware, bandwidth, numa

In various sources and also official ones from Intel, I get the number of max. 10.4 GT/s for the latest UPI interconnect, which connects for example Intel Xeon processors in the Skylake architecture. Now for the older Quick Path interconnects, I could find a lot of sources stating that with 2 bytes per transition and 6.4 GT/s, we get a bandwidth of 12.8 GB/s per link in one direction.

Now back to UPI: Is it still 2 bytes per transition, which means 20.8 GB/s per link per direction? I can not find any information about this on the internet except a German Wikipedia page [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_QuickPath_Interconnect) that is however annotated with the note that numbers might not be up to date.

Comment: A google search for "intel UPI bandwidth" found https://www.nas.nasa.gov/hecc/support/kb/skylake-processors_550.html#:~:text=The%20UPI%20runs%20at%20a,second%20(GB%2Fs). which connects GT/s and GB/s: 2 links between a pair of sockets means 41.6 GB/s aggregate bidirectional bandwidth, or 20.8 GB/s each direction, 10.4 per link.  Seems pretty clear if that source is accurate.